# Loading data from openweathermap.org

Tags: swift, session, openweathermap

I tried to receive data from https://openweathermap.org/ but I get:

> `nw_protocol_get_quic_image_block_invoke dlopen libquic failed`

```swift
    func performRequest(urlString : String){
        //1.create URL
        
        if let url = URL(string: urlString){
            
            // 2. Create a URL Session
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            // 3. Give the session a task
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: handle(data:  response: error: ))
            // 4. Start the task
            task.resume()
        }
    }

    func handle(data:Data?,response:URLResponse?,error:Error?){
        
    }
```